# Using Smartsheet API: How do I access user data after a user is authenticated and taken to redirect url?

Tags: node.js, django, oauth, smartsheet-api

Context: I integrated a Node.js Smartsheet Oauth flow into my Django app by having the login button in django direct the user to the /auth url on the Node server. Once the flow is done and user logs in through Smartsheet, the redirect URL from the Smartsheet dev tools takes the user back to the Django website.

Objective: I am trying to access the user data, so that before they log in a variable called user = undefined, and after they log in the variable called user is an object with a set of user data that comes from the smartsheet API. This object would include: id, email, first name, last name, etc...

I have tried a few approaches:

1. I tried to fetch data from the /callback url where the OAuth flow generates and saves token data, but I get rejections, maybe due to thoughtful security protocall
2. Ive tried to play with "raw token requests" for current user, maybe accessing them from the Node.js server and then sending data back through a post request. I haven't get it working and it seems incorrect to post user data as it comes, and have the django app try to match the user to their data once inside the django app.

Am I missing something obvious? How do I best grab user data from the user who has just logged in? I want to display their username for them, as well as mark their username to changes they make to the smartsheet files from the app.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the user chooses **Allow** in the popup dialog during the OAuth flow, Smartsheet redirects to the callback URL you specified, and includes a few query string parameters on the end of the callback URL. One of those parameters is the `code` parameter, a string value that you can subsequently use to obtain an API access token for that user.

For example, let's assume that this is the URL that the user is redirected to after they choose **Allow** in the popup dialog:

`http://localhost:3000/callback?code=sample6p9qisx6a&expires_in=599080&state=MY_STATE`

In this example, the value of the `code` parameter is `sample6p9qisx6a`.

At this point, you can issue a `POST /token` request to get an API access token for the user. The [Request an Access Token](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?javascript#request-an-access-token) section of the API docs describes how to issue this request. Notice that one of the parameters it requires is `code` -- set to the value of the `code` query string parameter received previously in the callback URL.

A successful response to the `POST /token` request will contain the property `access_token` as shown in this example:

```
{
    "token": {
        "access_token": "ll352u9jujauoqz4gstvsae05",
        "token_type": "bearer",
        "refresh_token": "e9x352a9mp4151le2505",
        "expires_in": 604799
    }
}
```

At this point, you can use the access token  to issue a [Get Current User](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?javascript#get-current-user) request: `GET users/me`. Note that the access token is specified as part of the  request's `Authorization` header, in this format (note: you'll replace the token `ll352...` in this example with the actual value of the `access_token` property you received in response to your previous `POST /token` request):

`Authorization: Bearer ll352u9jujauoqz4gstvsae05`

A successful response to the **Get Current User** request will be a [UserProfile object](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?javascript#userprofile-object) that contains all info about the user:

```
{
  "id": 48569348493401200,
  "email": "john.doe@smartsheet.com",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "locale": "en_US",
  "timeZone": "US/Pacific",
  "account": {
    "name": "Team Smartsheet",
    "id": 942513719853956
  },
  "admin": true,
  "licensedSheetCreator": true,
  "groupAdmin": true,
  "resourceViewer": true,
  "jiraAdmin": false,
  "salesforceAdmin": false,
  "salesforceUser": false,
  "alternateEmails": [
    {
      "id": 12345,
      "email": "altEmail1@smartsheet.com",
      "confirmed": true                
    }
  ],
  "title": "Senior Sales Representative",
  "department": "Marketing",
  "company": "Smartsheet",
  "workPhone": "",
  "mobilePhone": "206 123-4567",
  "role": "Sales",
  "profileImage": {
    "imageId": "u!1!8ljad7w9-aY!AsDeH0wWv1Y!y9VvAgUOFdg",
    "height": 1050,
    "width": 1050
  },
  "sheetCount": 3,
  "lastLogin": "2016-08-15T18:32:47Z",
  "customWelcomeScreenViewed": "2016-08-12T12:15:47Z"
}
```

Comment: Woah. This is so thorough!!! I had started to realize some of this as I read the documentation more carefully but you answered this so succinctly and completely!! Thanks!

Comment: Happy I could help!

Answer (score 0):

got this 100% working, but it was quite an intensive process to set up.

After a user clicks log in (from the django server), they get redirected onto the Node server where the start of the Oauth process takes them to the authorization url (frankly I used node b/c there was already sample code)

it then redirects the user back to the website with the authorization code is in the url.

then you have to extract the code from the url, and I tried to use that code with a react/redux thunk request, but CORS blocks requests from browsers, so I could not make this request in react.

instead I had to use a post request to send this code to the Django backend. Directly after react checks the return of the post request to find the pk (entry id) of its post request, and uses this to make a get/retrieve request to that specific entry id. this get request to the rest api ends up in views.py, where an external module/script is triggered that uses the request library and takes the authorization token (user_data.objects.last()). The requests were based on the curls on the website, but translated into requests. When the script is done running I have user data. This data is then patched into the database entry (partial update) and because python is synchronous, the get request cannot finish until the external scripts finish, and by then the data the get request needs is in the database.

Once the get request finishes, react parses the json, and posts it to the redux store (because I am using redux).

there is probably a better way (as I am new), but for anyone in the future looking for how to do this, it is very much possible in the way I described...